# Select * From table Order by TRIM(ALL [:nonalphnum:] FROM `title`)

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sql-order-by, trim

What I thought was a simple query is turning into a major headache.

I want to order by trimming all non-alphanum characters in title.

as in... sort the results alphanumerically but ignore any non-alphanum characters... not removing them from the database, just assume they are not there.

Comment: create a user defined sql function called REGEXP_REPLACE().. have it act like preg_replace() in php.. Then filter out symbols with a regular expression... might be cool.

Comment: BTW I bet this has been done 1000x... I would look it up :P

Comment: 5 seconds... https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#readme ... although I didn't check if it works in select statements, but could be copied/adapted

Answer (score 0):

I believe trim doesn't work with character classes. and your case is a poster example for some regular expression replace function ... which mysql doesn't provide afaik.

what you probably could do is: create an extra column where you write the title with alphanum only - with php - , (created when inserted or once for the existing rows) and then sort on that.

Comment: What about multiple trims? in the same query

Comment: well, as long as the chars you want to remove are just a few, this might work, but [:nonalphnum:] (whatever that might be) sound like an awful lot of different symbols ...

Answer (score 0):

OK, turn out there is a way. It's ugly, but it works, as I don't have to take out all the non-alphanumerics.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY TRIM(BOTH '"' 
FROM (TRIM(LEADING '$' 
FROM (TRIM(BOTH '\'' 
FROM (TRIM(BOTH '#' 
FROM (TRIM(BOTH '&' 
FROM (TRIM(BOTH '(' 
FROM (TRIM(BOTH '-' 
FROM `title`))))))))))))) ;
```